# Django : request.body isn't null but request.POST is null

Tags: python, django

I wanna test LOGIN function.
I used Insomnia to send signal.

like this:
[image]

I found request.POST is always null, but request.body is not.
In terminal, Output is as follows:
`print(request.body)` : `b'{\n\t"userid" : "TEST",\n\t"userpw" : "TEST",\n\t"created" : ""\n}'`
`print(request.POST)` : `<QueryDict: {}>`

My code in PyCharm:

models.py :

```
from django.db import models

class AppAddresses(models.Model):
   userid = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, default=False)
   userpw = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, default=False)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   class Meta:
      ordering = ['created']
```

serializers.py :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import AppAddresses


class AppAddressesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AppAddresses
        fields = ['userid', 'userpw']
```

urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from addresses import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('app_login/', views.app_login),
    path('app_signup/', views.app_signup),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

views.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .models import AppAddresses
from .serializers import AppAddressesSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

@csrf_exempt
def app_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST.get('userid', '')
        pw = request.POST.get('userpw', '')
        print(request.body)
        print(request.POST)

        login_result = authenticate(username=id, password=pw)

        if login_result:
            print("SUCCESS!")
            return JsonResponse({'code': '0000', 'msg': 'SUCCESS'}, status=200)
        else:
            print("FAILED!")
            return JsonResponse({'code': '1001', 'msg': 'FAILED'}, status=401)

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        query_set = AppAddresses.objects.all()
        serializer = AppAddressesSerializer(query_set, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)


# ... skip ...
```

As written above in views.py, I wanna get value `userid` and `userpw` using with `request.POST.get()`.
But It always returns empty. I have searched many posts but can't solve this yet.
Can anyone Help me Please?..

Comment: I added `{"userid" : "TEST", "userpw" : "TEST"}` in `admin_site.urls` before testing with Insomnia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.POST` returns form-encoded values and does not parse JSON from body

Considering you want to use DRF you could wrap your `app_login` function with [`api_view`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#wrapping-api-views) decorator, as it will automatically deserialize your parameters from JSON and have them accessible as `request.data`

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def app_login(request):
    ...
    id = request.data.get('userid', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`request.data`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#request-objects):

```
id = request.data.get("userid")
pw = request.data.get("pw")
```